# How to disable the Home tap gesture on home page but not on other pages in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uitapgesturerecognizer

**Xamarin.Forms implementation.**

I have home button on all pages and have implemented it in one file and render it on all pages.

Now, my requirement is if the user is on home page and if he taps home icon nothing should happen i.e should not navigate to home page by flicking the page(this is the current implementation).

I tried if else to my logic but may be that is not how it has to be. (i.e)

```
if
{
  //user on home page. Do nothing. 
}
else
{
  //navigate to Home.
}
```

Here is my image with tap gesture command

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="OneD_Icon_Small.png" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="5,5,0,0">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HomeCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Comment: Set hide the home button in Home Page,

Comment: @Prasanth i do not want to hide the icon I just want to disable its tap event on home page and not on other pages.

Please guide ASAP.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I don't need the type of current page.
I just want to disable the tap gesture command on Home page and no where else.

Comment: Can you provide the code about the tap gesture command in your xaml?

Comment: sure
Here is my image with tap gesture command
 <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="OneD_Icon_Small.png" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="5,5,0,0">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HomeCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>

Comment: Get the object of the home button and set isEnable = false in home page and rest of the page set IsEnabled = true

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: I would suggest having a base command and virtual canexecute in the base viewmodel in the homepage viewmodel  you can override it in and return false to disable it. Rest of the other pages can still have the base implementation from the base viewmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in each contentPage.xaml

set the name of contentPage and pass it as Parameter of CommandParameter

For example in MainPage

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App12"
             x:Name="myPage"
             x:Class="App12.MainPage">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

        <Image Source="OneD_Icon_Small.png" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="5,5,0,0">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HomeCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .,Source={x:Reference myPage}}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And in the ViewModel

```
public class TapViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {        
   ICommand homeCommand;
   public TapViewModel()
   {
      // configure the TapCommand with a method
      homeCommand = new Command(OnTapped);
   }
   public ICommand HomeCommand
   {
     get { return homeCommand; }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   void OnTapped(object s)
   {
     var page = s as ContentPage;

     if (page.GetType() == typeof(MainPage))
     {
        //user on home page. Do nothing.
     }

     else
     {
        //navigate to Home.
     }

    }

}
```

**Note:**  object s is the contentPage ,and you can do something you want.

Comment: `Command` constructor has an additional parameter `canExecute` which is a `Func<bool>` that can be used to prevent execution of the command.